# How to show only public and private sites of a user in theme

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-theme

I need help in printing private and public sites of which the user is a member.

By resuing the code from the post ([How do I get Sites of which the user is a member in Liferay theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469131/how-do-i-get-sites-of-which-the-user-is-a-member-in-liferay-theme/12477508#12477508)) I am able to get the sites, but it gives users' private and public pages too.

How to avoid printing user's private and public pages, since I need only Communities or rather Sites.

```
<ul>
    #foreach($site in $user.mySites)
       #if ($site.hasPrivateLayouts())
              <li><a href="/group${site.friendlyURL}">$site.descriptiveName</a></li>
       #end
       #if ($site.hasPublicLayouts())
              <li><a href="/web${site.friendlyURL}">$site.descriptiveName</a></li>
    #end
    #end
</ul>
```

**Environment: Liferay 6.1**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of using the mysites section for user you should use the user services and group service to fetch the user groups.

```
#set($userId = $getterUtil.getLong($request.remote-user))
#set($userLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService"))
#set($user = $userLocalService.getUserById($userId))
#set($groupLocalService=$serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.GroupLocalService"))
#set($userGroup = $groupLocalService.getUserGroup($companyId,$getterUtil.getLong($userId)))

$userGroup
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the same code with some changes:

```
<ul>
    #foreach($site in $user.mySites)        
        <!-- if it is NOT a user's public or private site only then print it -->
        #if(!$site.isUserPersonalSite())            
            #if ($site.hasPrivateLayouts())
                <li><a href="/group${site.friendlyURL}">$site.descriptiveName</a></li>
            #end

            #if ($site.hasPublicLayouts())
                <li><a href="/web${site.friendlyURL}">$site.descriptiveName</a></li>
            #end
        #end
    #end
</ul>
```

Note the `if(!$site.isUserPersonalSite())` code, if the site is a user's public or private site (i.e. containing user's public & private pages) then don't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

Update the following properties in your `portal-ext.properties` in liferay root

```
# Deactivate Personal Community with *private* pages:
layout.user.private.layouts.enabled=false   

# Deactivate Personal Community with *public* pages:
layout.user.public.layouts.enabled=false
```

Comment: These properties would disable the user sites but the OP is asking if he can display the Sites without displaying the user sites in the list. The User sites need to be there but should not be listed through the theme.